# (swift) ways to debug CrashIfClientProvidedBogusAudioBufferList when the AudioStreamPacketDescription is nil?

Tags: ios, swift, core-audio, swift2

i'm getting a `CrashIfClientProvidedBogusAudioBufferList` exception when attempting once my 
`AudioConverterFillComplexBuffer` callback returns. What are the possibile reasons why this exception would be thrown?

for reference, here is my call

```
AudioConverterFillComplexBuffer(audioConverterRef,  
fillComplexCallback,  
&convertInfo,  
&framesToDecode,  
&localPcmBufferList,
```

& the callback:

```
func fillComplexxCallback(myConverter: AudioConverterRef, packetNumber: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt32>,   
ioData: UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioBufferList>, aspd: UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioStreamPacketDescription>>,  
userInfo: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) -> OSStatus {  

    var convertInfo = UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioConvertInfo>(userInfo).memory  

    if (packetNumber.memory > (convertInfo.audioBuffer.mDataByteSize / convertInfo.numberOfPackets)) {  
        packetNumber.memory = (convertInfo.audioBuffer.mDataByteSize / convertInfo.numberOfPackets)  
    }  

    ioData.memory.mNumberBuffers = 1  
    var buffer = AudioBuffer(mNumberChannels: 2, mDataByteSize: convertInfo.audioBuffer.mDataByteSize, mData: ioData.memory.mBuffers.mData)  
    ioData.memory.mBuffers = buffer  

     /* if the following is uncommented out, a exception is thrown */
    // aspd.memory = convertInfo.packetDescriptions 
    packetNumber.memory = convertInfo.numberOfPackets  
    convertInfo.done = true  

        return 0  
}
```

here's `AudioConvertInfo's` struct:

```
struct AudioConvertInfo {
    var done: Bool! //conversion of audio is finished
    var numberOfPackets: UInt32!
    var audioBuffer: AudioBuffer!
    var audioPlayer: CCPlayer!
    var packetDescriptions: AudioStreamPacketDescription!

    init(done: Bool?, numberOfPackets: UInt32?, audioBuffer: AudioBuffer?, packetDescriptions: AudioStreamPacketDescription!, audioPlayer: CCPlayer!) {
        self.done = done
        self.numberOfPackets = numberOfPackets
        self.audioBuffer = audioBuffer
        self.packetDescriptions = packetDescriptions
        self.audioPlayer = audioPlayer
    }
}
```

I can't seem to find any solid documentation around. I've noticed was the aspd (`AudioStreamPacketDescription`) is returning nil. This is important to determine one packet in a buffer of audio data where the sizes of the packets differ or where there is non-audio data between audio packets. This code will throw an exception on aspd.memory = convertInfo.packetDescriptions , but if the code is commented out - the CrashIfClientProvidedBogusAudioBufferList is thrown. My theory is that this callback will work fine if i figure out why the AudioStreamPacketDescription is nil

Comment: Probably I can help you if you provide sample project where your crash takes place.

Comment: There's not nearly enough info here for a complete answer. What is AudioConvertInfo? Where does it come from / when is it created? How are you configuring the converter? What is your input data and where are you calling the function from?

Comment: @Visput  i updated the question. also, i can share with you the repo if you provide me your email & github contact info

Comment: @jtbandes updated the question. also, i can share with you the repo if you provide me your email & github contact info

Comment: @3254523, you can find my github on my profile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like `AudioStreamPacketDescription is nil` is not a problem.
According to Apple documentation it can be nil, basically it depends on audio format:
[AudioConverterComplexInputDataProc](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/AudioConverterServicesReference/index.html)

> `outDataPacketDescription: UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioStreamPacketDescription>>` - If **not NULL** on input, the audio converter
>   expects this callback to provide an **array of
>   AudioStreamPacketDescription** structures on output, one for each packet
>   of audio data you are providing in the ioData parameter.

[AudioConverterFillComplexBuffer](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/AudioConverterServicesReference/index.html)

> `outPacketDescription: UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioStreamPacketDescription>` - On input, must point to a block of memory
>   capable of holding the number of packet descriptions specified in the
>   ioOutputDataPacketSize parameter. (See Audio Format Services Reference
>   for functions that let you **determine whether an audio format uses
>   packet descriptions**). If not NULL on output and if the audio
>   converter’s output format uses packet descriptions, then this
>   parameter contains an array of packet descriptions.

The real problem is placed in `AudioConvertInfo` structure in this line:

```
var packetDescriptions: AudioStreamPacketDescription!
```

Structure keeps just single `AudioStreamPacketDescription` structure.
Then you use it in `fillComplexCallback` function:

```
outDataPacketDescription.memory.memory = convertInfo.packetDescriptions
```

So you are trying to set single `AudioStreamPacketDescription` structure to parameter `outDataPacketDescription` that expects array of `AudioStreamPacketDescription` structures (not just single instance).

This problem can be fixed by keeping and using array of `AudioStreamPacketDescription` structures.
Updated version of `AudioConvertInfo` structure:

```
struct AudioConvertInfo {
    var done: Bool!
    var numberOfPackets: UInt32!
    var audioBuffer: AudioBuffer!
    var audioPlayer: CCPlayer!
    var packetDescriptions: UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioStreamPacketDescription>!

    init(done: Bool?, numberOfPackets: UInt32?, audioBuffer: AudioBuffer?, packetDescriptions: UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioStreamPacketDescription>!, audioPlayer: CCPlayer!) {
        self.done = done
        self.numberOfPackets = numberOfPackets
        self.audioBuffer = audioBuffer
        self.packetDescriptions = packetDescriptions
        self.audioPlayer = audioPlayer
    }
}

// Usage:
convertInfo = AudioConvertInfo(done: false, numberOfPackets: numberPackets, audioBuffer: AudioBuffer(mNumberChannels: 2, mDataByteSize: numberBytes, mData: &iData), packetDescriptions: packetDescriptions, audioPlayer: self)
```

Updated version of `fillComplexCallback` function:

```
func fillComplexCallback(inAudioConverter: AudioConverterRef, ioNumberDataPackets: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt32>, ioData: UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioBufferList>, outDataPacketDescription: UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioStreamPacketDescription>>, inUserData: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) -> OSStatus {
    var convertInfo = UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioConvertInfo>(inUserData).memory

    if convertInfo.done == true {
        ioNumberDataPackets.memory = 0
        return 100
    }
    ioData.memory.mNumberBuffers = 1
    let buffer = convertInfo.audioBuffer
    ioData.memory.mBuffers = buffer

    if outDataPacketDescription != nil {
        outDataPacketDescription.memory = convertInfo.packetDescriptions
    }

    ioNumberDataPackets.memory = convertInfo.numberOfPackets
    convertInfo.done = true

    return 0
}

// Usage:  
status = AudioConverterFillComplexBuffer(audioConverterRef, fillComplexCallback, &convertInfo!, &framesToDecode, &localPcmBufferList!, nil)
```

Hope it will resolve your issue.